# Append a tag to spesific loaction of HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I have these tags in my HTML,

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="options"></div>
    <div id="searchField"></div>
    <div id="options"></div>

    <div id="results">
        ***<!-- I want to add elements here -->***
        <div id="pagenumber">
        <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

What would be the javascript code that appends children above `id="pagenumber"` and inside `id="results"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the following approach:

```
var pagenumber = document.getElementById('pagenumber'),
    results = document.getElementById('results'),
    newElem = document.createElement('div');

results.insertBefore(newElem, pagenumber);
```

To insert *after* the `pagenumber` node you could use:

```
results.insertBefore(newElem, pagenumber.nextSibling);
```

References:

- [`node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore).

Answer (score 0):

This would be helpful to you..

```
 var results=document.getElementById('results');
 var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
 var divIdName = 'myDiv';
 newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
 newdiv.innerHTML = '<p>Test</p>';
 results.appendChild(newdiv);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that add to the _end_ of the "results" div?